# mqtt client publish based on incoming message conditions

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I am experimenting with mqtt with python paho mqtt library and a mqtt client mobile app with the test.mosquito.org server/broker.

This basic script works below connecting to the test.mosquitto server where I can publish a message from a mobile mqtt client app to this script and this script can also publish to the mobile app every 20 seconds a test message via the `def publish(client):` function.

```
import random
import time
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client


broker = 'test.mosquitto.org'
port = 1883 


# generate client ID with pub prefix randomly
client_id = "test_1"
topic_to_publish = f"laptop/publish"
topic_to_listen = f"mobile/publish"
topic_to_wildcard = f"testing/*"

username = ""
password = ""


def connect_mqtt():
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            client.subscribe(topic_to_listen)
            print(f"Connected to MQTT Broker on topic: {topic_to_wildcard}")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

    client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
    client.username_pw_set(username, password)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(broker, port)
    client.on_connect = on_connect  # Define callback function for successful connection
    client.on_message = on_message  # Define callback function for receipt of a message
    return client


def publish(client):
    msg_count = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(20)
        msg = f"hello from {client_id}: {msg_count}"
        result = client.publish(topic_to_publish, msg)
        
        # result: [0, 1]
        status = result[0]
        if status == 0:
            print(f"Send {msg} to topic {topic_to_publish}")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to send message to topic {topic_to_publish}")
        msg_count += 1



def on_message(client, userdata, msg):  # The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
    print("Message received-> " + msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))



def run():
    client = connect_mqtt()
    client.loop_start()
    publish(client)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Can someone give me a tip on how to modify the `def publish(client):` function not to be a `while loop` that will fire off messages every 20 seconds but to only publish if the message from the mobile app received equals a string `"zone temps"`?

Am I on track at all removing the `publish(client)` from main `run` function as well as the while loop from `def publish(client):`? Thanks any tips greatly appreciated. What I am running into is I am missing something when I run this modified version there is no message exchange between at all.

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):  
    print("Message received-> " + msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))
    
    if str(msg.payload) == "zone temps":
        publish(client,"avg=72.1;min=66.4;max=78.8")
        

def run():
    client = connect_mqtt()
    client.loop_start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m also beginner; but ill create a variable to is it publish or listening, like:

`phoneAppListener = 0`

and also

`if str(msg.payload) == "zone temps":`

when i print my payload it looks like:

`b'payload'`

firstly you need to split your payload like:

`tempMsgHolder = str(msg.payload).split("'")`

when you do this. tempMsgHolder[1] is your pure payload.

`if tempMsgHolder[1] == "zone temps": phoneAppListener = 1`

phoneAppListener value make the decision 0 is listen, 1 is publish. on your publish loop you set this

`phoneAppListener == 1: publish your message`

```
import random
import time
import threading
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client


class moduleDatas:
    broker = ('test.mosquitto.org')
    port = (1883)

    # generate client ID with pub prefix randomly
    client_id = "test_1"
    topic_to_publish = f"laptop/publish"
    topic_to_listen = f"mobile/publish"
    topic_to_wildcard = f"testing/*"

    username = ""
    password = ""

# Create clients object:
  # You can create mqtt client obj using same pattern. Client has different on_msg or ex. 
mqttClient_1 = mqtt_client.Client(moduleDatas.client_id) # You can create what ever you want to create a new thread

def mqttClientConnect():
    mqttClient_1.connect(moduleDatas.broker[0], moduleDatas.port[0])
    mqttClient_1.loop_start() # It creates daemon thread while your main thread running, this will handle your mqtt connection.

@mqttClient_1.connect_callback()
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print(f"Connected to MQTT Broker on topic: {moduleDatas.topic_to_wildcard}")
    else:
        print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

@mqttClient_1.publish_callback()
def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print(mid) # If publish is success its return 1 || If mid = 1 publish success. || You can check your publish msg if it return failed try to send again or check your connection.

@mqttClient_1.message_callback()
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    temp_str = str(message.payload).split("'")
    if temp_str[1] == "zone temps":
        msg = "hello world" # <-- Your message here. Some func return or simple texts
        mqttClient_1.publish(topic= moduleDatas.topic_to_publish, payload= msg, qos= 0)

def mqttClientSubscribe():
    mqttClient_1.subscribe(moduleDatas.topic_to_listen)

def threadMqttClient1():
    mqttClientConnect()
    mqttClientSubscribe()

def buildThreads():
    threads= []
    t = threading.Thread(target=threadMqttClient1(), daemon= True)
    threads.append(t)
    # You can create on same pattern and append threads list.
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    while True: # this will your main thread, you can create an operation, ill go with just idling.
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    buildThreads()
```

Comment: Thanks any chance for a complete answer? Like what the entire script would look like? Ill hit the green check box

Comment: Edited code block, also i add some threading. You can create clients. You can also change broker and port tuple to list. I was read some info for difference between tuple and list. Tuple's only read only, List has read and write operation. Tuple's make sure to var is not change while in runtime.

Comment: Cool thanks. How does the threading work in the code? I have yet to learn parallel processing.... Any high level incite appreciated.